# Get Jenkins BUILD Details from NodeJS process

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am running a NodeJS project in Jenkins and would like to have current build details.

I am using  below code inside index.js

```
process.env.JOB_NAME
process.env.BUILD_NUMBER
```

But they report undefined. Even in `process.env` Object I could not find any Jenkins variables found.

How can I get them?

Answer (score 3):

You can add any variable in a build step. For example in linux, just add shell execute step:

```
export JOB_NAME=${JOB_NAME}
```

After that you can use the process.env.JOB_NAME from node.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, just add **bat** execute step:

```
SET JOB_NAME=%JOB_NAME%
```

After that you can use the process.env.JOB_NAME from node.